# System.Int32[] c#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write code that makes a union between array a and b (AUB), but when I want to print the combined array. the console prints `System.Int32\[\]`.

For context, if my

```
array a = { 1, 3, 5, 6 }
```

and my

```
array b = { 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

my union array should be

```
combi = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 }
```

but like I said, `combi` prints out as `System.Int32\[\]`

I don't know if it's the way I'm doing the union or if its the way I'm printing it. I'm also trying to do a

- A intersection B and A – B

But I haven't tried anything of those yet, I would appreciate if you have any tips.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;

namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("size of A? ");
            int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Value of A:");
            int[] ans = new int[a];

            for (int i = 0; i < ans.Length; i++)
            {
                ans[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());
            }

            Console.WriteLine("size of B?");
            int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Value of B:");
            int[] anse = new int[b];

            for (int i = 0; i < anse.Length; i++)
            {
                anse[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.In.ReadLine());
            }

            var combi = new int[ans.Length + anse.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < combi.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(combi + " ");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Tim's answer is the correct one, use `string.Join(",", combi)`. A small best practice tip: to ensure inputs are validated you should prefer `int.TryParse()` to `Convert.ToInt32()`. The convert method can throw a format or overflow exception which will crash the app for bad input or number over the int range. The try parse method returns a bool indicating if parsing was successful, as well as an output parameter containing the parsed int. Read up on it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0#system-int32-tryparse(system-string-system-int32@))

Answer (score 1):

> when i want to print the combined array the console prints
> System.Int32[]

If you write `Console.Write(someObject)`, the method tries to find an overridden `ToString` in `someObject`. If there is none [`System.Object.ToString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.tostring?view=net-7.0) is used which just returns the fully qualified name of the type of the Object, which is "System.Int32[]" in case of an `int[]`.

If you want to print out an array of integers one approach would be to use [`string.Join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=net-7.0):

```
string spaceSeparatedList = string.Join(" ", combi);
```

Now you have a space-separated list of integers.

Answer (score 0):

In the code You have just initialized the size of the array of **Combi Array** not assign the values

First you have to add **Array a** and  **Array b** values into **combi array**

Then try to print into union,see below code for the reference:

```
        List<int> combi = new List<int>();

        foreach(var first in ans)
        {
            combi.Add(first);
        }
        foreach (var second in anse)
        {
            combi.Add(second);
        }
        combi.Sort(); 
        string result = string.Join(",",combi);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```